# How to change the code from JavaScript to the Angular/Typescript way

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have this code:

```
app.component.ts

    export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

      targetElement: HTMLElement;
      viewer: any;

      constructor () {}

      ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.targetElement = document.getElementById('wrapper'); // This line
      }


  app.component.html



    <div #wrapper id="wrapper" [innerHTML]=targetElement></div>
```

I don't want to use

```
document.getElementById('wrapper');
```

Is there an Angular way to change the line marked: `// This line`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular way is to use template reference with `@ViewChild` decorator

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('#wrapper') test: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   //use this.test
  }
}
```

Note this line `@ViewChild('#wrapper') test: ElementRef;`

`wrapper` refers to the template reference on the html element

Another way would be to directly inject `ElementRef` in `constructor`.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('#wrapper');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Template ref can be used if you want to access the dom.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('wrapper')
  wrapper: ElementRef
  viewer: any;

  constructor () {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }

}


  <div #wrapper></div>
```

this.wrapper will have the dom node which can be used to access